# Does anyone know if xcache functions are atomic?

Tags: php, atomic, xcache

I'm wondering which xcache functions are atomic. I know that `xcache_inc()` and `xcache_dec()` are both atomic. I dont know if `xcache_get()` and `xcache_unset()` are atomic.

Comment: What means "atomic" when you're talking about `get`?

Comment: [definition of atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability)

Comment: I know what it means. I cannot think of "non-atomic" sample of `get`. Can you give an example when `get` could behave like it is non-atomic?

Comment: i have no idea. I'm not a php pro or anything otherwise I would know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Feature List](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/FeatureList) says that XCache supports "atomic get/set/inc/dec".

So `get` is atomic, whatever that means. (It probably just means that `get` never returns an in-between value, which is more or less the same thing as atomic `set`.)

Also, since `set` is atomic, I see no reason why `unset` wouldn't be atomic, too.